# Understand SonarQube and its testing coverage

Tags: sonarqube, test-coverage

i am a Beginner with SonarQube and really tried to google and read a lot of community pages to understand which functions SonarQube offers.

What i dont get is: What does the test coverage in SonarQube refer to? 
If it says for example that the coverage on New Code is 30% what does new code mean?

And when does SonarQube say that a issue is a bug? Is the analyzed code compared to a certain standard in order for SonarQube to say that there is a bug?

I hope someone with more knowledge about SonarQube can help me understand it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

**Test coverage** (also known as code coverage) corresponds to the proportion of the application code (i.e., code without test and sample code) that is executed by test cases out of all application code of the code base.

SonarQube does not compute code coverage itself. Instead coverage is computed and uploaded by external code coverage tools (e.g., cobertura, JaCoCo). SonarQube presents code coverage at different levels (e.g., line coverage, condition coverage); see https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/metric-definitions/#header-9.

**Coverage on new code** refers to the proportion of code that is both covered and added (or modified) since a certain baseline out of all added and changed code since the same baseline. The baseline can, for example, be the previously analyzed code state or the code state of the previous commit. That is, this metric expresses how extensively *changes* have been tested. Note that 100% coverage does not mean that code has been perfectly tested; it just says that all code has been *executed* by test cases.

**Issues** in SonarQube do not necessarily represent bugs. Usually most issues are actually not bugs but are problems affecting code maintainability in the long term (e.g., code duplications) or violations of best practices. Still, some issues can represent bugs (e.g., potential null-dereferences, incorrect concurrency handling).
Note that an issue can also be false a positive and therefore not be a problem at all.

Most issues are identified with static code analysis by searching the code structure for certain patterns. Some can be uncovered by simple code searches (e.g., violation of naming conventions). Other analyses / issue classes may additionally need data-flow analyses (null-dereferences) or require byte-code information.